# Improve querying of Extended Events target file

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012, extended-events, xquery

As part of our server estate monitoring, I am adding extended events to pick up warnings, blocking etc and I'd like to periodically (Every couple of minutes) query the event file to collect the data. I have been using the below to query data using xQuery, but it seems to be quite slow. I am aware of using a fileoffset as an option to optimise, but beyond that, are there any ways in which I can better improve predicates as been below?

```
    SELECT 
         event_data
        ,n.value('@timestamp', 'DATETIME2') DtTimeStamp
        ,n.value('(action[@name="collect_cpu_cycle_time"]/value)[1]', 'bigINT') CollectCpuCycleTime
        ,n.value('(action[@name="collect_system_time"]/value)[1]', 'DATETIME2') CollectSystemTime
        ,n.value('(action[@name="last_error"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') LastError
        ,n.value('(action[@name="collect_system_time"]/value)[1]', 'datetime2')             CollectSystemTime
        ,n.value('(action[@name="task_time"]/value)[1]', 'bigint')                          TaskTime
        ,n.value('(action[@name="client_app_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)')              ClientAppName
        ,n.value('(action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)')              ClientHostName
        ,n.value('(action[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)')                DatabaseName
        ,n.value('(action[@name="nt_username"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)')                  NtUserName
        ,n.value('(action[@name="server_instance_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(255)')         InstanceName
        ,n.value('(action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', 'INT')                            SessionID
        ,n.value('(action[@name="client_pid"]/value)[1]', 'INT')                            ClientPID
        ,n.value('(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')                         SQLText
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                CAST(event_data as XML) event_data
            FROM 
                sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('C:\Temp\EE_QueryWarnings*.xel', null, null, null)
        ) ed
    OUTER APPLY
        ed.event_data.nodes('event') (n)
    WHERE
        n.value('@name', 'varchar(MAX)')    = 'missing_column_statistics'
    AND
        n.value('@timestamp', 'DATETIME2')   >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-10,GETUTCDATE());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is [Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq) instead of T-SQL to process XE data in Powershell or .NET application. The QueryableXEventData class can process XE data directly from target files or from the live event stream.

The live steam source is generally appropriate for events that occur relatively infrequently (as in your monitoring use case) whereas the file source most useful for high-frequency event use cases (e.g. capturing rpc and batch completed events for tracing).

Assuming your goal is inserting events into a table for forensics, below is a PowerShell example and target table DDL. One can use SqlBulkCopy instead of trickle inserts for high-frequency events.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.missing_column_statistics (
      Timestamp datetimeoffset
    , Name varchar(100)
    , collect_cpu_cycle_time decimal(20, 0)
    , collect_system_time datetimeoffset
    , last_error int
    , task_time decimal(20, 0)
    , client_app_name varchar(100)
    , client_hostname varchar(100)
    , database_name sysname
    , nt_username varchar(100)
    , server_instance_name varchar(100)
    , session_id int
    , client_pid int
    , sql_text nvarchar(MAX)
);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.missing_column_statistics(Timestamp);
```

PowerShell script:

```
# class with actions/fields of interest
class MissingColumnStatisticsEvent {

    [DateTimeOffset]$Timestamp
    [String]$Name
    [UInt64]$collect_cpu_cycle_time
    [DateTimeOffset]$collect_system_time
    [UInt32]$last_error
    [UInt64]$task_time
    [String]$client_app_name
    [String]$client_hostname
    [String]$database_name
    [String]$nt_username
    [String]$server_instance_name
    [UInt16]$session_id
    [UInt16]$client_pid
    [String]$sql_text

    MissingColumnStatisticsEvent($event) {
        $this.Name = $event.Name
        $this.Timestamp = $event.Timestamp
        $this.collect_cpu_cycle_time = $event.Actions["collect_cpu_cycle_time"].Value
        $this.collect_system_time = $event.Actions["collect_system_time"].Value
        $this.last_error = $event.Actions["last_error"].Value
        $this.task_time = $event.Actions["task_time"].Value
        $this.client_app_name = $event.Actions["client_app_name"].Value
        $this.client_hostname = $event.Actions["client_hostname"].Value
        $this.database_name = $event.Actions["database_name"].Value
        $this.nt_username = $event.Actions["nt_username"].Value
        $this.server_instance_name = $event.Actions["server_instance_name"].Value
        $this.session_id = $event.Actions["session_id"].Value
        $this.client_pid = $event.Actions["client_pid"].Value
        $this.sql_text = $event.Actions["sql_text"].Value
    }

}

# insert event data into target table
Function Insert-MissingColumnStatisticsEvent($event) {
    $insertQuery = @"
INSERT INTO dbo.missing_column_statistics (
      Timestamp
    , Name
    , collect_cpu_cycle_time
    , collect_system_time
    , last_error
    , task_time
    , client_app_name
    , client_hostname
    , database_name
    , nt_username
    , server_instance_name
    , session_id
    , client_pid
    , sql_text
)
VALUES (
      @Timestamp
    , @Name
    , @collect_cpu_cycle_time
    , @collect_system_time
    , @last_error
    , @task_time
    , @client_app_name
    , @client_hostname
    , @database_name
    , @nt_username
    , @server_instance_name
    , @session_id
    , @client_pid
    , @sql_text
);
"@

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($targetDatabaseConnectionString)
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($insertQuery, $connection)
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@Timestamp", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTimeOffset)).Value = $event.Timestamp
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@Name", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100)).Value = $event.Name
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@collect_cpu_cycle_time", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Decimal, 20, 0)).Value = $event.collect_cpu_cycle_time
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@collect_system_time", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTimeOffset)).Value = $event.collect_system_time
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@last_error", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int)).Value = $event.last_error
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@task_time", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Decimal, 20, 0)).Value = $event.task_time
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@client_app_name", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100)).Value = $event.client_app_name
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@client_hostname", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100)).Value = $event.client_hostname
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@database_name", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 128)).Value = $event.database_name
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@nt_username", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100)).Value = $event.nt_username
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@server_instance_name", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100)).Value = $event.server_instance_name
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@session_id", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int)).Value = $event.session_id
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@client_pid", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int)).Value = $event.client_pid
    ($command.Parameters.Add("@sql_text", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1)).Value = $event.sql_text
    $connection.Open()
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
}

# ############
# ### MAIN ###
# ############
try {

    # load assemblies needed for QueryableXEventData
    $sharedPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared" # path varies by SQL tool version
    $xeCore = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($sharedPath, "Microsoft.SqlServer.XE.Core.dll")
    $xeLinq = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($sharedPath, "Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll")
    Add-Type -Path $xeLinq
    Add-Type -Path $xeCore

    $xeSessionConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=XE ETL" # run in master database context for live stream
    $targetDatabaseConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=XE ETL"
    $sessionName = "EE_QueryWarnings"

    # get events from file target
    # $events = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.QueryableXEventData("DC:\Temp\$sessionName*.xel")

    # get events from live session
    $events = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.QueryableXEventData(
       $xeSessionConnectionString,
       $sessionName, 
       [Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.EventStreamSourceOptions]::EventStream,
       [Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.EventStreamCacheOptions]::DoNotCache)


    # Stream source will consume continuously until this script or XE session is stopped.
    # File source will read all XE files and exit.
    foreach($event in $events) {
        if($event.Name -eq "missing_column_statistics") {
            $missingColumnStatisticsEvent = New-Object MissingColumnStatisticsEvent($event)
            Insert-MissingColumnStatisticsEvent -event $missingColumnStatisticsEvent
        }
    }
}
catch {

    throw

}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for sending that through, I'm a bit of a notice to Extended Events, so  I'm gradually picking things up. Instead of simply just using xe files, I think I'll use a combination of ring buffer and xe files allowing me to capture current and previous data. Something I do need to consider with this however is execution context, and in particular for large xe files. Am I correct in thinking that your script would use the execution context of the source server to shred xml?

Comment: @Krishn, the is no XML with QueryableXEventData. This reads the binary XE stream directly from a live session or file, which is why it performs so much faster. You don't even need to connect to a database engine with a file source, although the example in my answer does so for the ETL process..